# C++ Virtual Inheritance weird behavior

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

```
struct A {
public:
    A() {
        std::cout << "A" << std:: endl;
    }
    void foo() { std::cout << "foo is called from A"; }
};

struct B : virtual A {  };
struct C : virtual  A {  };
struct D : B, C { D() { std::cout << "D" << std::endl; } };

struct E : D { };
struct F : D {};
struct G : E, F {}; 


int main()
{
    G g;
    g.foo();
}
```

The output code is :

- A
- D
- D
- foo is called from A

This makes no sense. Object D is constructed twice. Why doesn't the compiler complain that foo is ambiguous?
How does G know that there is only one definition on foo ? (in this case D is made twice and I did not use virtual inheritance but somehow it knows.)
I honestly thought that E and F should inherent also virtually from D in order to avoid the ambiguous definition of foo. 
Can anyone offer a good explanation? 
Compiled in VS 2017 Windows.
You can imagine this line of inheritance as a ***double diamond problem.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This makes no sense.

Why? This is exactly what virtual inheritance is for. There is only a single `A` sub-object inside `G`. The specifier sticks as we go down the hierarchy, so even though `G` has two `D`'s, they both share an `A`.

Comment: That is not logical. How does the compiler know that multiple D should contain the same base A? In the case I presented struct B : virtual A { }; struct C : virtual A { }; explicitly tell the compiler that anyone that inherits from B or C should explicitly instantiate A once but struct D : B, C does NOT.

Comment: @GabrielGrigoras - It knows it, because that's the semantics of the `virtual` keyword when applied to bases. `virtual` means that the class agrees to share its base sub-object with any other class that inherits **virtually** in the **most derived object** type (`G` in your example). No matter how complex your hierarchy is, all classes for which `A` is a virtual base will share the same base instance. This is also why the most derived object type, and only it, is the one responsible for the initialization of this `A`.

Comment: TY. Best explanation. I missed "most derived object type".

Answer (score 4):

> Object D is constructed twice.

This is because the object has two `D` bases. One through `E` and another through `F`.

> Why doesn't the compiler complain that foo is ambiguous?

Because there is only one `A` base. This is because it is a virtual base. There is always exactly one virtual base sub object of its type for each concrete instance.

Here is a rough ASCII-art of the inheritance:

```
non-virtual  |   virtual
             |   A
 ____________|__/
/   /  /  /  |
B  C  B  C   |
 \/    \/    |
  D     D    |
   \   /     |
    E  F     |       bases
_____\/______________________
      G              concrete
```

> How does the compiler know that multiple D should contain the same base A

Because it knows that all of those A-bases are virtual.

Comment: That is not logical. How does the compiler know that multiple D should contain the same base A.  In the case I presented struct B : virtual A {  };
struct C : virtual  A {  }; explicitly tell the compiler that anyone that inherits from B or C should explicitly instantiate A once but struct D : B, C does NOT.

Comment: I don't understand how the compiler knows that all who inherent from D should (even if it's multiple types) should use the same A.

Comment: @GabrielGrigoras The compiler sees the keyword `virtual`. The compiler knows what it means. It means that there is one virtual base of that type shared across the entire derived object.

Comment: So that means that it's somehow inherited?